# SPI COMM in Atmega328p

Tags: c, atmega, atmega32

I am working on Atmega328p using Arduino Uno board, my task is SPI comm using register level,
can anybody explain what is meant by  DD_MOSI is left shift "1<

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are referring to the code examples on page 172 of the ATmega328p datasheet (http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/ATmega48A-PA-88A-PA-168A-PA-328-P-DS-DS40002061A.pdf). In the example, they use `DD_MOSI` as a stand in for the bit position of the control bit for the pin associated with MOSI signal, which on the MCU in question is PortB[3]. So, when they have the line:

```
DDR_SPI = (1<<DD_MOSI)|(1<<DD_SCK);
```

You can translate that to fill in the associated port and bit shifts:

```
DDRB = (1<<DDB3)|(1<<DDB5); // Since SPI in on Port B, MOSI is the third pin and SCK is the 5th pin, see page 91-92
```

Comment: okay, how we can make PINs DDB3 and DDB5 output by (1<<DDB3)|(1<<DDB5) please explain this......! I have confusion in left shit (<<).

Comment: In order for the pins `PostB[3]` and `PortB[5]` outputs, bits 3 and 5 in the `DDRB` need to be set. So, you could just set the bits directly (`DDRB = 0x28`) but to make the code more readable, it's nice to have names on the bits that are being set. The way the headers define names (like `DDB5` for the bit controlling the data direction for pin `PortB[5]` in `DDRB` register) is as the bit number instead of the mask (`DDB5` = 5, not 0x20), so you need to get a 1 to bit 5 using the value 5. And that's what shifting does (`1 << 5 = 0x20`).